# Apache, Django and Mod_WSGI Issue

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

**[SOLVED]**
**I did the setups to substitute from runserver to apache**. As you can notice below. The Django app isn't running over apache. Could you guide me, please?

mod_wsgi was installed with no issue and I could check it when I run index.py with the following code:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
     start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type','text/html')])
     return ['<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>']
```

I have a Django default application built over startproject, startapp, makemigrations, migrate and are running fine over python webserver (runserver). www.host.com:8000/admin. I mean, The Django Dev Server works perfectly.

I'd like to run Django over Apache.

**httpd.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi .py
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/djangoproj>
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi .py
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess contacts python-path=/var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj:/var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup contacts

  WSGIScriptAlias /contacts /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/djangoproj/wsgi.py

  ServerName contacts
  <Directory /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/djangoproj>
     <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
     </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /static/ /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/static
  <Directory  /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/static>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/VEnvs/proj/djangoproj/djangoproj/wsgi.py file**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoproj.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**When I ran**: www.host.com/contacts **I got**:
404 Not Found
The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.

Could you please help me on it?

**Versions:**

```
Python 3.5.1 over virtualenv 15.0.2; 
Django 1.9.6; 
Apache (httpd) 2.4.6 over RedHat.
mod_wsgi 3.4.12
```

**EDIT:** 
**I SOLVED THE ISSUE ABOUT**: 
The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.
Thank you all!

Comment: You've hosted your WSGI app on /contacts, so obviously /djangoproj won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry but It was a typo (and I fixed it). I double checked and the correct one is www.hots.com/contacts. Apache has the correct one:  WSGIScriptAlias /contacts /var/www/VEnvs/valoreiovenv/djangoproj/djangoproj/wsgi.py

Comment: Well, you haven't defined any URLs in Django for that path, only for /admin.